# sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Tags: python-2.7, email-attachments, smtplib

(user_mail, ','.join(recipient), mail.as_string())

The above code produces error of expected string but tuple found. How should I fix this? Any solution?

Comment: Some more code would help us to help you

Comment: recipient = []                                                                                                         db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "', user = ''', paswd=''', db=''')                 cursor = db.cursor()                                                                                  cursor.execute('select email from user where email is not null')        rows=cursor.fetchall()                                                                            for item in rows:                                                                                           recipient.append(item)

Comment: I am asking for the code that could explain the problem and help us to find the solution. You can post the code that sends email like smtplib.login and other codes.

Comment: mailServer.sendMail(user_mail, ','.join(recipient), mail.as_string())  will this do?  it says this line is having problem. I try to read emails from database and make python to send email with attachment to them.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify recipients in a string . Below is an example you can specify recipients like this.

```
user_email = "someone@example.com"
recipients =  ["email1, email2, email3"]
```

Comment: I tried it and it says typeError: sequence item 3: expected string, tuple found

Comment: Try the edit I hope that this works. I did use lists and it worked fine but I don't know why it's not working in your case

Comment: Attribute error : str object has no attribute append 

Comment: The one that I commented above,  recipient.append(item)

Comment: use `recipients = [item for item in recipient]`

Comment: Invalid syntax came out for the use recipients = [item for item in recipient]